# Terraform json with variables

Tags: terraform

I have a json with a list of projects in the cloud.
Those projects are in different folders.

**# projects.json**:

```
{
    'project-1': {
        "project_id": "project-1",
        "folder_id": "${var.folders.dev.id}"
     },
    'project-2-prd': {
        "project_id": "project-2-prd",
        "folder_id": "${var.folders.prd.id}"
     }
}
```

Now in a TF file I want to read this list and put into module. So far I've been doing this with a TF object, now I need to move to JSON as I will be dynamically replacing this list. And this declaration stopped doing it's work as should...

```
locals {
  projects_config = try(
    jsondecode(file("${path.module}/projects.json")),
    {}
  )
  # other variables
}
module "projects" {
  for_each local.projects_config
  source              = "../templates/project_creator"
}
```

...as my folder_id from a dynamic variable has become a normal string :)

```
      ~ folder_id           = "123456789" -> "${var.folders.dev.id}"
```

I've tried reading json file with combination of jsondecode() and file() functions, but it obviously is ignoring the variable I need.

**Is there a way in TF to parse this JSON like it would be a .tf.json file and folder_id would be treated as a variable, not a string?**
I really don't want to complicate this with a map of folder names and folder ID's.

Comment: Try with `var.folders.dev.id`, but I don't think that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jsonencode` format implements only JSON decoding; it does not include any Terraform-specific expression evaluation.

Since this file is in your module's own directory anyway, one option would be to rename it so that Terraform will treat it as a normal configuration file using [the JSON variant of the Terraform language](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax/json), and adjust it to directly declare the [local value](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) containing the data you want.

For example, you could rename the file to `projects.tf.json` and then use the following file contents:

```
{
  "locals": {
    "projects_config": {
      "project-1": {
        "project_id": "project-1",
        "folder_id": "${var.folders.dev.id}"
      },
      "project-2-prd": {
        "project_id": "project-2-prd",
        "folder_id": "${var.folders.prd.id}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is a JSON equivalent of the following native syntax declaration:

```
locals {
  projects_config = {
    "project-1" = {
      "project_id" = "project-1"
      "folder_id"  = var.folders.dev.id
    }
    "project-2-prd" = {
      "project_id" = "project-2-prd"
      "folder_id"  = var.folders.prd.id
    }
  }
}
```

Terraform will automatically include this file's declarations as part of the module, so this file would totally replace your existing declaration of `local.projects_config`. The JSON values assigned to the properties of `"locals"` are subject to [expression mapping](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/syntax/json#expression-mapping), which means Terraform will treat each of your leaf JSON strings as a string template and therefore interpolate the `var.folders.dev.id` and `var.folders.prd.id` values as you want.

---

If you want to do this with a generic JSON file rather than a Terraform language JSON file then you'll need to implement your own mechanism for inserting the dynamic values, by first loading the JSON using `jsonencode` and then post-processing it to deal with the placeholders.

That seems like a lot of unnecessary work though, since your goal is just to declare a local value based on the JSON data anyway, which the above solution achieves by using a Terraform language configuration file directly.

Comment: Wow! You were such a great help. I tried .tf.json file before, but forgot that it's just a syntax, and I could declare locals there, and rather declared only projects before. After adding locals to the tf.json file "infrastructure matches the configuration."! Thank you very much Martin!